# Simplest way to solve this card problem

Tags: probability

In a Poker match, asumming 52 cards (13 of each type). This is the state:

- On my hand I have cards [3] and [4] of any type.
- In table, there are these cards: [1] [2] [3] [?] [?], this is, two unknown cards and 1 [3].
- There are other two players, each one with two unknown cards. So in the deck there are remaining 52 - 6 = 46 cards.

The question is: **what is the probability of other players to get Three of a kind composed of [3]. (Only three of a kind, no four) in "river"?**

I can try to solve this problem partioning probabilities first for table, then for each case probability for next player, then for each case for the last player. But I'll need to solve the same problem for a table for 5 players, so this will be very laborious.

Comment: Can they get their three of a kind *before* the river, or must they make their three of a kind *on* the river?

Comment: They can before the river

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a straightforward way to solve it.  It doesn't really get that much more complicated with more players.

The important cases are these:

1. Both turn and river are $[3]$.  All of your opponents get three $[3]$'s (they're all in the community cards).
2. Either turn or river is $[3]$, and one of your opponents' hole cards is $[3]$.  At most one of your opponents gets three $[3]$'s.
3. At most one of your opponents has both hole cards as $[3]$.  That opponent already has his three $[3]$'s.
4. If two opponents each have one $[3]$, no one gets three $[3]$'s.

For Case 1, take out the two $[3]$'s and choose what cards the others get (which doesn't matter).

For Case 2, choose the opponent that has the $[3]$, then choose which one of the two he gets.  Then pick his other hole care.  Next choose whether the other $[3]$ shows up on the turn or the river, then pick the other community card.  Finally, pick the hole cards for the other opponents.

For Case 3, choose the opponent that gets both $[3]$'s.  Then choose the river and turn cards, and the hole cards for everyone else (none of which matters).

For Case 4, choose the two opponents that get one $[3]$ apiece, then choose which one they each get.  Choose their other hole card.  Choose the river and turn card, and the hole cards for everyone else.

Add up the combinations from Cases 1 to 3, and subtract the number from Case 4.  Divide by the total number of combinations to get the probability.